# Identifying MOSFET (P9DVA) and diode (AD6) Markings

Tags: mosfet, diodes, power-electronics, identification, buck

I need help identifying a MOSFET and a diode in a circuit, specifically on the Pololu board [D24V25F5](https://www.pololu.com/product/2850).

While researching, I came across information about a diode (NSVR0340) with the AD4 marking. However, the diode in my circuit is marked as AD6, and I'm uncertain if this difference is significant.

Additionally, I've encountered difficulty in finding any markings on the MOSFET used in the circuit.

Any assistance in correctly identifying these components and understanding the significance of the marking differences would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The MOSFET is a [Si2318CDS](https://www.vishay.com/docs/67030/si2318cds.pdf) from Vishay Siliconix (P9 is the significant code here).

picture from [LCSC](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/VishayIntertech-Si2318CDS_T1GE3/C14498):
[image]

- The diode is a [NSR0340HT1G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nsr0340h-d.pdf) from ONSEMI. (AD is the significant code here, the last character contains assembly location or date code information).

Note: Please verifiy that the package is a SOD-323.

picture from [LCSC](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Onsemi-NSR0340HT1G/C90392):
[image]